# how to work with multiple forms in single page

Tags: forms, yii

I have a model(table with 2 fields name(pk) and text). I need to show the data in these forms and update it from the page. 
I'm able to show the form by using this

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

but how to show the content from the table into each section and how to update the data.

index.php is like this:

```
<p>some & Text</p>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
    </p>
    <p>Some more  Text</p>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
    </p>
    <p>Little More Text</p>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>    
    </p>
```

my _form.php is like this:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'settings-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'text'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'text',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'text'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Submit' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

What should be my url for the index.php in order to show the content from the table.(at the moment I'm using localhost/webapp/controller.. and its displaying with form 3 times.

Comment: You will need to clarify yourself here : do you want to display 3 seperate records in 3 forms or 3 parts of the form with text in between ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.. I've solved my self using Collecting Tabular Input
I'm able to achieve what I'm looking for with 
Collecting Tabular Input
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

Thanks all :)

my controller:

```
public function actionBatchUpdate()
    {
            $item = new Model;

            $items=Model::model()->findAll();





            if(isset($_POST['Model']))
            {

                    $valid=true;
                    foreach($items as $i=>$item)
                    {
                            if(isset($_POST['Model'][$i]))

                            $item->attributes=$_POST['Model'][$i];
                            $valid=$item->validate() && $valid;
                            if($valid)$item->save();
                    }


            }

            // displays the view to collect tabular input
            $this->render('batchUpdate',array(
                            'items'=>$items));

    }
```

my view file:

my view file batchupdate.php is:

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<table>

<?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>
<tr style=" border-bottom: solid 1px black;">
<p><td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]name",$htmlOptions=array('disabled'=>'disabled')); ?></td></p>
</tr>


<tr style=" border-bottom: solid 2px black;">
<p><td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($item,"[$i]text",$htmlOptions=array ('rows'=>8,'cols'=>60));?></td></p></tr> 

 <tr style=" border-bottom: solid 1px black;">
<p><td><?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save');?></td></p></tr>
<tr>
<td><hr size="10" width="100%" /></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>


<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it like this:

suppose your action is "update" and you need to update the record with `id = 1`,
so you can pass this id to update action like `update?id=1`, or via `post` method, then you can get this id in your `update` action, then fetch data for this id:
assuming you have get id via `post`..

`$results = Modelname::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('id'=>$_POST['id']))`

then you can pass this result in your form,

`<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model, 'results' => $results)); ?>`

then in your `_form`:
you can update the table data like this:

`<?php echo $form->textField($model,'mobile',array('value'=>$results['mobile'])) ; ?>`

Thanks.